# Error converting parameter in Linq query Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

For SEO, I delete Turkish characters and spaces.

But I can't format the LINQ parameter, 
it gives the error.

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(p => p.ProductNameTR
>           .trCharToEnChar() == __productName_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
{
    TContext context = new TContext();
    return filter == null ?
        context.Set<TEntity>().ToList() :
        context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
}

public static string trCharToEnChar(this string str)
{
    var newStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        newStr = str.Replace(" ", "_");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ı", "i");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ö", "o");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ü", "u");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ğ", "g");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ş", "s");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ç", "c");
        newStr = newStr.Replace("ü", "u");
    }

    return newStr;
}

public List<Products> GetProductsByProductNameTextConvert(string productName)
{
    return _productDal.GetAll(p => p.ProductNameTR.trCharToEnChar() == productName);
}
```

Comment: Better would be to have a persisted computed column of ProductNameTR with the characters replaced. Than you dont have to do it in your query every time, and table indices could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are using EF Core 3.0 or greater and EF is unable to translate the expression `p => p.ProductNameTR.trCharToEnChar() == productName` to SQL.

Prior to EF Core 3.0 the whole set of data would be returned and then further filtered by applying the expression to the result set, returning the filtered result set.

A quick fix would be to change `_productDal.AsEnumerable()` to `_productDal.ToList()` to force EF to retrieve the data before filtering. `AsEnumerable()` isn't sufficient to cause EF to execute the query at the database.

Answer (score 1):

Because LINQ does not know how to translate your `trCharToEnChar` method to SQL, you can use `.ToList`, `AsEnumerable()` or other methods as suggested by error itself to solve it. With `.ToList()` after data is loaded, any further operation (such as select) is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory:

```
context.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable().Where(filter).ToList();
// Or context.Set<TEntity>().ToList().Where(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: I saw your answer.
Once I've received the entire list, filtering is detrimental to this performance, if I don't have a solution, I'll do it last.